# KnockoutJS foreach failure to print json array in HTML

Tags: arrays, json, knockout.js

I have this code for my viewmodel wonder why its not printing my array in HTML (hoi = being printed properly)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var MasterViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;
    debugger;
    self.ListOfSup = ko.observableArray([{ "Id": 1, "Name": "EpicT", "Brand": "X", "OriginCountry": "SH", "Reviews": null }, { "Id": 2, "Name": "EpicT", "Brand": "X", "OriginCountry": "SH", "Reviews": null }, { "Id": 3, "Name": "SuperT", "Brand": "X", "OriginCountry": "SH", "Reviews": null }, { "Id": 4, "Name": "DBl", "Brand": "X", "OriginCountry": "SH", "Reviews": null }, { "Id": 5, "Name": "Wins", "Brand": "X", "OriginCountry": "SH", "Reviews": null }, { "Id": 6, "Name": "Oxand", "Brand": "X", "OriginCountry": "SH", "Reviews": null }, { "Id": 7, "Name": "Whey", "Brand": "GS", "OriginCountry": null, "Reviews": null }]);
    self.Hoi = ko.observable("Hello Knockout");
}

var masterModel = new MasterViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(masterModel);

})
```

Here is the code for HTML:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: Hoi">Ko</h2>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ListOfSup">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Brand"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Driving me to madness. Is my array not Json enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid HTML: you are missing the `table` elements around the `tbody`

In this case the browser (at least Chrome) cannot interpret the sole `tbody` and 
just removes it completely from the DOM

So the fix is very simple: add the `table`:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: Hoi">Ko</h2>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: ListOfSup">
      <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: Brand"></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c11n4ky5/).

Comment: Thanks for your solution!